# Play framework Java client

Tags: playframework

We have a multi-window java application with a complex UI.  We want to migrate the architecture to a client-server design by moving the data model and data management to a server and retaining everything else on the client.  So rather than reading data from the local network, the app is fetching data from the server.  I want to use the Play! framework with bidirectional asynchronous sockets for handling the data transfers.  All Play! examples have browser/html views.  I haven't found any examples where the client is a POJC (plain ole Java client).  Play! seems to be completely structured around browser clients.  Does anyone have an example of using a POJC instead?  Or advice on designing views and controllers?  My hope is to offer both solutions: a POJC for multi-panel desktop machines and a browser-version for mobile and tablet devices.  I would like therefore to design it so that the application will support both.

Comment: maybe you could find a way to leverage the WebSockets API?  I don't see anything else - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaWebSockets

Comment: @rees:  Looking at Akka, I see there is a more general API which provides bidirectional sockets between Actors which can be local or remote. Ideally, clients could then be POJCs or browser apps, and servers could be local or remote. This is more general than what appears to be supported and described in the Play! Framework even though Akka is part of the "stack" distributed by Typesafe.  If Play! does support distributed networks, it would be nice to have an example in the docs describing it. Akka examples are very basic so I've nothing to start from and will have to build from scratch.

Comment: An example of "using a POJC" is a bit too vague imo. Why not just setup a REST API to send/receive data? This would make it quite simple to display in a POJC and a web client. There are a lot of examples of building REST services in Play! Do you have large data or some type of real time requirements that make HTTP a poor choice? Perhaps if you described your data/communication requirements better it would be easier to suggest a particular solution.